How do I generate a package dependency graph of a python environment that is inside a docker file
I have a docker file that contains a virtual python environment in /app/venv/bin/python.  I know how to generate a list of packages, using
docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash mydocker:1.0.0 -c "pip list"

but I want to get a picture showing all the dependencies as a graph.  I see there is a tool pipdeptree to do that, but how can I run it against my environment inside the docker?

Does the Dockerfile setup include something like a requirements.txt file that lists all of the packages in it?  It might be easier to use that to generate the dependency listing without involving Docker at all.

Using docker run you can do the following

mount a writable volume,
create a new venv,
install pipdeptree into it
run pipdeptree against the original venv in the docker
generate a dot file in the writable volume
convert the dot to a png, or whatever

To make this easier, create a bash function, such as
function drun { docker run --entrypoint /bin/bash --volume ./output:/output mydocker:1.0.0 -c "$*" ; }

Create a directory
mkdir ./output

Create the venv
drun python -m venv /output/venv

Look in your output to see if venv got created.  If so,
drun source /output/env/bin/activate ; pipdeptree --python /app/venv/bin/python --graph-output dot > /output/mygraph.dot

After you get the dot file, you can convert to image using
dot -Tpng ./output/mygraph.dot > ./output/mygraph.png

and you can run that last command outside docker.
